# VSCode - autocomplete for loops

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-formatter

I used to write C code with Visual Studio, and whenever I wrote "for" and then pressed TAB, it was automatically completed to an entire for loop, i.e.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
{

}
```

Is there a way to enable that in VSCode as well? Even by using some extension?
Thanks!

Comment: maybe take a look here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: This kind of editor function is called *snippets*.

Comment: Just fyi: This sort of shortcut is unlikely to be useful in C++, where we often iterate over a loop with *iterators* - with range-based for loops being very common and useful (for their cleanliness). Even for old-style loops, `length` is unlikely to be the variable name you're comparing too; more likely to be something like `vec.size()` or `arr.size()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to enable that in VSCode as well?

Yes, you can add `snippets` and [customize](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) them according to your needs if the corresponding snippet is not already available, as shown below for the `for` loop shown in your question.

##### Step 1

Go to **Files** -> **Preferences** -> **User Snippets**

##### Step 2

After clicking on the **User Snippets** you will be prompted with a menu with different options as shown in the screen shot attached. Click on the option saying: *New Global Snippets File*

[image: image 1]

##### Step 3

When you click on *New Global Snippets File*, a file will open where you can add your required snippet. Since you've given the `for` loop that you want in C++, I will write the content that you want to place in that file:

```
{
  "For Loop": {
    "prefix": ["for", "for-const"],
    "body": ["for (size_t i = ${1:0} ;i < ${2:length}; i++)", "{\t${0://add code here}", "}"],
    "description": "A for loop."
  }
}
```

##### Step 4

Save this file with the content shown above and then you will be able to use this snippet. For example, next time you write `for` you will be prompted with different options and you can press `TAB` for selecting that option and that snippet will be used at that point, as shown in the below screenshot :

[image: sc 2]

[image: sc3]