# Insert line using shortcut in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I often print text and variables to my terminal for debug purposes. I am tired of always typing the same code. Is there a way I can define a shortcut that will insert this line for example:

```
std::cout << "Debug: " << std::endl;
```

Subsequently I can modify it to my needs. I found the shortcuts in VS Code under Ctrl K+S, but there you can only modify, not add them.

Comment: Yes you can create your own emmet/shortcut/snippet as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72446085/vscode-autocomplete-for-loops/72446833#72446833)

Comment: if you use windows : ctrl  + v , if you use mac command + v